# Вывод TV параметра в чанк'е

Tags: modx

Приветствую!

Использую `Wayfinder` в `MODX` для вывода навигации по странницам, 
`[[Wayfinder? startId=`9`level=`1`&rowTpl=`stroyka`]]`
необходимо к каждой ссылке в этом меню добавить картинку из tv параметра статьи ( каждая статья имеет этот тв параметр ) на которую ведет ссылка..
В чанк'е 'stroyka' вот это: 
`<li><a href="[+wf.link+]" title="[+wf.title+]" [+wf.attributes+]><img src="[+TVimg_stroy +]" width="100" height="100" ><br/>[+wf.title+]</a></li>`

У каждой статьи есть TV параметр ( `img_stroy` ) - фото, его и нужно выводить в `src` у `img` тега.

Вопрос в том как мне его правильно подставить в `src="???"`, а то я получаю `<img src width=...`

Comment: извиняюсь первый раз на сайте, не смог оформить код :-/

Comment: ок, решил сам: [(base_url)][+img_stroy+]